# I can't see my Object in Modeling Workspace

Tags: modeling, objects, workspaces

I created an *Object* in the *Layout Workspace*, when I switch to the *Modeling Workspace* vertices disappear. When I create a new file, it works.
I upload an MP4 to google drive.Please check it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6XDjp_vD-76H-lDxmtez-0TWMDqScwr/view?usp=sharing
[image]
[image]

Comment: No,I did not hid the mesh.And it's not working by ALT + H .

Comment: Perhaps your viewport is extremely zoomed out? Try having the object selected and press numpad period.

Comment: It's not working.Please check the video I uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

solved.Thank you very much NGCHunter2!
[image]

Global view shows all 3D objects in the scene. Local view isolates the selected object or objects, so that they are the only ones visible in the viewport.
<kbd>Numbpad /</kbd>  is use to toggle Local View

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!